# I am having issues with Stack Exchange chat, and feel I may have been hacked. What can I do?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-accounts

Someone from stackexchange hacked into my file and added another account. It is disrupting my chat time. Please tell me how to delete a profile! I already tried creating a new email but they found out what it was.

Comment: What do you mean, added another account? Added another Arqade account? Another network site account?

Comment: No rpg super user and something else. I wanted to talk to you. :,(

Comment: @Stizzle84 Have you visited any of these sites in the past few days? Sometimes, they ask you for permissions with your account, and when doing so, adds an account.

Comment: I don't seem to see those sites associated with your network account, when I look at what sites you have accounts on. Do you use a separate login for those?]

Comment: I dont know i am scared cause he just put up a bountey!

Comment: Can you link me to where this is happening?

Comment: No i am on mobile but see for yourself on arqade it says i have an active bounty. Also it was only a few minutes ago but i just now got home from a hockey tournament.

Comment: Can you guys delete them not my arquade

Comment: I don't see any other accounts listed for you. As far as I can tell, all you have is an arqade account.

Comment: @ash I think that's his point

Comment: "he just put up a bountey" - Do you mean to say that [this bounty](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154675/how-do-i-get-invited-to-realms) was not your doing?

Comment: Reason for [status-norepro] - Shog (who answered below) used to be a Community Manager at Stack Exhange. If there was anything wrong, they would've been able to find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No one has hacked into your account. Or done anything else with your account. You've been using it for the past couple hours, and that's the only thing that's happened with it in several days.